# nodejs azure web app giving http 431 error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, http-error, azure-webapps

I had a node app hosted as an azure web app on Linux environment. The node service handles events requests as a GET method.  The application was working fine and all of a sudden since last 2 days it started throwing 431 error.

there was another similar question posted [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059648/azure-web-app-node-js-azure-ad-error-431) but this is not the case here. I do not have AAD enabled
have also verified below areas

1. no change in the node app
2. no change on the client side sending the get request
3. no explicit headers are sent. this was verified by making simple postman calls as well

what could have gone wrong here? any help?

Answer (score 0):

Is it only happening for certain users? When I've seen this in the past, it was because we kept user role & state in the token (which generally does get passed in a header) and for some "test" users that had access to absolutely everything, that token was too large and we had a 431. For pretty much any other user things were fine.

Our fix was to use a key-value store (could be SQL, CosmosDB, etc.) and the user token was now an ID that mapped to the value in the data store, and the role & state info was moved there.