# Azure App Service - Fail after enabling Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, identity

We have an app which get data from Azure DevOps Services using RestAPI with token. Without authentication it is working fine.

After enabling authentication get errors 500/431 without any explanation. Authentication set for single tenant and with new application registration.

---

THE ONLY WAY TO GET AROUND THIS PROBLEM WAS TO USE A CONTAINER BUILD FROM AZURE - USE VS CODE TO PUBLISH & BUILD  - USING A CUSTOM CONTAINER FAILED ALWAYS

---

I tried the following without success:

- Setting - WEBSITE_AUTH_DISABLE_IDENTITY_FLOW - [Azure Web App + Node.js + Azure AD = Error 431](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059648/azure-web-app-node-js-azure-ad-error-431)
- Added specific permission for - Azure DevOps Services on the Identity provider tab.

  [image]

  [image]

Any advice would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error **`500`** may occur if you have enabled App Insights monitoring on client-side.

***Please check whether you have enabled that option or not like below:***

```js
APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLE = true
```

If it is enabled, disable it by assigning **`false`** parameter as suggested in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959549/randomly-getting-error-500-in-azure-app-service-when-downloading-angularjs-templ) by L. González.

These **500/431** errors occur due to many reasons and to know the exact issue behind the error, try enabling diagnostic logging.

[image]

To know more about diagnostic logging please refer this [***MsDoc***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)

Try restarting the App Service and raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/) if still the issue persists.

**Reference:**

[how do I fix the azure web app error 500? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072178/how-do-i-fix-the-azure-web-app-error-500)

Comment: checked - Appinsights disabled - same problem